# Question about bounding boxes to handle false positives

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection

I have trained a model to detect vehicle number plates. The issue is that it returns matches of partial plates, with high confidence. To eliminate partials I want to add two new boxes to the images with partial left side and partial right side and give them different classes. See image attached as explanation

[image: Visual explanation]

My question is this: will the overlapping boxes confuse the detection of the main class?

Using Tensorflow with faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.

Thanks,
Alan.

Edit: Changed title from "false negatives" to what I really meant "false positives"

Answer (score 0):

No each class is computed separately. The model tries to find 3 things in the image the `leftpart` the `rightpart` and the `numplate` independent of one another.

Else-wise, the `numplate` would be computed as the union of the other two boxes, so there still wouldn't be an issue if the boxes overlapped. However, this is clearly not the case, given the image you provided.